# Soldering CPUs/GPUs/FPGAs - temperature issue

Tags: soldering, temperature, surface-mount

I am thinking about making my own FPGA board and soldering using reflow. The tutorials I've read all say the process requires temperatures in excess of 220 °F. However, at least according to [this datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/Search/m_ProductDetail.aspx?Altera/EP3C40U484C7N/&qs=jblrfmjbeiExk2fcimV2wQ==&gclid=Cj0KEQjw6pGfBRD09M-TmYTBzqIBEiQAcRzH5yOI9uXSTqaUeCRgiNgvv7vGWzZWAbAldXfw_7Y0LKYaAiNv8P8HAQ), FPGAs have "max operating temperatures" below 200 °F. How does one then solder an FPGA?

EDIT: I have a new question in response to the answer given. Why would the max operating temperature differ from the max soldering temperature?

Comment: You don't try to operate it while soldering it. A different part of the datasheet specifies the allowable soldering temperature profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soldering temperatures are normally in excess of 200°C (400°F).

The soldering guidelines for Xilinx Pb-free packages are [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp427.pdf). Usually lead-free soldering requires somewhat higher temperatures than eutectic Sn63-Pb37 solder.

It's not a problem to have brief exposure to soldering temperature of 220°C or even higher.

[image]

Edit:

The max **operating junction temperature** is the maximum temperature of the IC die with voltage applied (typically 125°C for an FPGA). High current densities on a chip combined with high temperatures eventually can cause failure due to metal migration.

The outside would have to be much cooler than that. The maximum **storage temperature** is the long-term maximum temperature with no voltage applied (typically 150°C for an FPGA). High continuous temperatures can degrade the package or cause impurities to diffuse in the chip.

Soldering is a short-term one-time (or occasional, at most) exposure (measured in seconds), so the damage caused, for example, by diffusion of impurities, is limited.

Comment: Why does the max op temp differ from the max soldering temp?

Comment: Please see edit.